# How can I get all-time stats for migrations from my site?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, migrated-questions

One of my sites is discussing adding a custom migration path to a site we have overlap with.  As a moderator I wanted to get some data about past migrations to inform that discussion.  I didn't find a way to get all-time totals per destination.  I can count -- by hand! -- all of the outbound migrations for a destination, and I can see a summary of migrations and how many were rejected for the last 90 days only.  For questions older than 90 days, I can't see aggregate information and the only way to find out about rejections is to click through on each one to look.

Is there some way for a moderator to get the same kind of data we get on the 90-days page, but for longer?  Ideally we'd be able to enter a date range, but if that's hard then just having the all-time list would be helpful in discussions like this.  (A date range would have been helpful in my case so we could limit the stats to migrations since the candidate target site was created.)  A 90-day period doesn't provide enough data to be meaningful on smaller sites.

I'm not asking for something to be implemented (this is an infrequent need and there are things I'd much rather the developers be working on).  I'm hoping there's a way to do it with tools already in place (which includes SEDE, but since migration stubs get deleted after 30 days I don't know if that helps).

Comment: I think you can do it by scraping `/tools/posts/migrated/away` (which requires authentication since it's 10k-only). You can tell which ones have been rejected because they have [closed] rather than [migrated] after the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to improve the tools. I'm not sure when we're going to be able to do that, but we definitely need to improve the tools. Until we have, this is what I suggest:

- Look at the last 90 days of mod-only manual migrations. If there are less than 10 - 15 of them, stop - the problem isn't big enough to warrant a migration path.
- If more than 10 - 15 questions have been lobbed over, have more than 80% of them been well-received? If so, ***just ask for the migration path*** on either meta site. We'll dig into the database as we research it.
- If you're seeing 80% or fewer of them being well-received, it's probably not a good idea to set up the path.

This also assumes there's no special caveats that might trip folks up. Are posts on the target site considered to be off-topic unless they're of a specific pentameter (as a crazy illustrative example)? That's not going to be obvious to everyone voting to migrate, so make sure the success rate isn't *because* only moderators have been handling migrations manually.

I can say, if a few mods (which also tends to be at least a couple of our most experienced users) think it's a good idea, it's probably worth looking into and we'll run some numbers for you. The request shouldn't be any more onerous than that (and wouldn't be if we had better tools in place), so just put the heavy lifting on our side and ask for it if you really think it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I know the CM team is super-busy, which is why I asked what *I* could do before bugging y'all.  This definitely helps, particularly the thresholds before moving on.